# How to download a file with js

Tags: javascript, file, button, download, audio-recording

I have this function , it is a voice recorder, and I want it to ask the person to download the recording after recorded.

This is the stop function, it already saves the recording online to listen to it if the person wants, but after the person leaves it deletes the recording, so I want it to ask the person to download the file to local folders, so they could listen offline.

```js
function parar() {
    clearInterval(tiempo_parar);
    clearInterval(contador);
    // Stop the recording
    recording = false;
    document.getElementById("temporizador_falta").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("grabar").innerHTML = sGrabar;
    document.getElementById("canvas_general").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("pintar_ruta").innerHTML = sGenerandoAudio;
    document.getElementById("parar").style.display = "none";
    // we flat the left and right channels down
    var leftBuffer = mergeBuffers(leftchannel, recordingLength);
    var rightBuffer = mergeBuffers(rightchannel, recordingLength);
    // we interleave both channels together
    var interleaved = interleave(leftBuffer, rightBuffer);
    // we create our file
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + interleaved.length * 2);
    var view = new DataView(buffer);
    // RIFF chunk descriptor
    writeUTFBytes(view, 0, 'RIFF');
    view.setUint32(4, 44 + interleaved.length * 2, true);
    writeUTFBytes(view, 8, 'WAVE');
    // FMT sub-chunk
    writeUTFBytes(view, 12, 'fmt ');
    view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
    view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
    // stereo (2 channels)
    view.setUint16(22, 2, true);
    view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
    view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true);
    view.setUint16(32, 4, true);
    view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
    // data sub-chunk
    writeUTFBytes(view, 36, 'data');
    view.setUint32(40, interleaved.length * 2, true);
    // write the samples
    var lng = interleaved.length;
    var index = 44;
    var volume = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
        view.setInt16(index, interleaved[i] * (0x7FFF * volume), true);
        index += 2;
    }
    // our final binary blob
    var blob = new Blob([view], {
        type: 'audio/wav'
    });
    // Save in local

    var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
    var link = window.document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'respuesta.html';
    link.href = url;
    document.getElementById("pintar_ruta").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("capa_respuesta").style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById("respuesta").src = url;
}
```

It could also work with keeping the file longer and add a button to download from the server, but I don't know how to do that. Help please :(

I tried creating a button already, but as the file doesn't exist until the recording is done, the button doesn't download anything or sends you to an url that don't exist, even after the audio is done.

Comment: Why stack overflow posted that empty? ‍♂️‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Create an a-tag with the url as a href and put the property/boolean attribute **donwload** on that a-tag.

**Note:** A boolean attribute is an attribute that doesn't have a value (like download, disabled et). It can be set using an empty string as the value!

Change your code to:

```
var link = window.document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.innerText = 'Download your recording';
link.setAttribute('download','')
```

And then attach the link to your html

```
document.querySelector('yourParentElement').append(link)
```

Comment: You mean this?:  <a href="" download="" src="#" target="_blank" id="down">Download</a>  " document.querySelector('down').append(link) ..... Did I do something wrong?, somehow it is not working :(

Comment: it actually askes me to download the web page file, instead of the recording

Comment: No, I mean follow the code I've posted - actually replace the corresponding part of your cod with my code and see what happens? Have you done that?

Comment: yes I did that, I just commented the <a> tag, because the rest you wrote it on your answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry then I am at loss. I really thought (since previous experience) that setting the whole data-url as href and setting the property download would do the trick.